# Downloading a zip file using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download, requestjs

I'm having trouble downloading a zip file in an AngularJS application. The setup is an AngularJS app with a fairly lightweight node backend using Hapi. What I'm trying to do is click a button in Angular to make a call to the Angular Apps backend, the backend then makes a request to a separate service for the zip file, and that zip file then needs to be returned to the AngularJS app.

In the backend I have this (using the requestjs simple HTTP client):

```
download: (id)->
    deferred = Q.defer()
    file = ''
    fileLength = 0

    #    writer = fs.createWriteStream('server_version.zip')
    #    writer.on 'finish', ->
    #      deferred.resolve(stream.data)
    #      console.log 'done'

    stream = request( {
        url: "#{download_url}"
        encoding: null
        headers:
            'X-Secret-Token': <SECRET_TOKEN>
            'Content-Type': 'application/zip'
    })#.pipe(writer)

    data = []

    stream.on 'data', (chunk)->
        data.push chunk

    stream.on 'end', ->
        result = Buffer.concat(data).toString();
        return deferred.resolve(result)

deferred.promise
```

The backend portion of the app seems to work because if I uncomment the pipe and send it to fs for writing, then the file gets written to the backends file system every time. The problem is I don't want to write the data to the backend, I want to pass it back up to the AngularJS frontend. In my frontend I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$scope.download = ->
    $scope.selectedItem.download().then (response)->
        blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
        console.log 'blob:', blob
        #url = $window.URL or $window.webkitURL
        #$window.location = url.createObjectURL(blob)
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "#{$scope.selectedItem.name}.zip") if blob
        console.log 'File saved'
```

The problem is that my download always comes back corrupted. I think I need to figure our a way to either pass the stream back to the frontend and parse it there, or else wait for the whole stream in the backend and concat it into something the front end can use. I have tried using the `.on 'data'` event to do that, but the zip file is still corrupted.

How can I pass the download zip (or stream) from the backend up to the frontend?

**Update** -

`$scope.selectedItem.download()` calls a service that makes an `$http` call to the AngularJS apps backend. The `$http` call should wrap the response (the binary response from the `download` function in the node backend) in a promise, which is returned to the controller.

The api service call:

```
deferred = $q.defer()
$http({
  method: verb
  url: url
  params: params
  data: body
  headers: headers
}).success (result)->
  Logger.debug '---- HTTP REQUEST DONE (SUCCESS) ----'
  Logger.debug 'Result: ', result
  deferred.resolve(result)
.error (err)->
  Logger.error '---- HTTP REQUEST DONE (ERROR) ----'
  Logger.error 'Error:', err
  showLogin() if err?.statusCode is 401
  deferred.reject(err)
```

Comment: What does `$scope.selectedItem.download()` return? If that's a `$http` then `response` may not be what you think it is

Comment: `selectedItem.download` is an $http call, but should wrap the response in a promise. I've updated my question to include that call.

Comment: Sorry, just posted the update!

Comment: does it return `deferred`? Is an anti-pattern to use `$q` this way with `$http` but that probably isn't the problem

Comment: yes, it returns `deferred.promise` later in the function. This is working with all other requests so I don't think that's the issue in this case.

Comment: only thing i can suggest is create a simple zip file with a couple of ultra basic files in it and try with a known file source like that